# Como ajusto este texto que esta a la derecha hacia el centro

Tags: html, css

[image: Quisiera lograr esto]

Dejo el codigo acá para acceso a la imagen, la idea que tengo es hacer algo cómodo a la vista. Que no desaparezca de golpe tipo 0 a 100

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(177, 73, 73);
    opacity: 90%;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(177, 73, 73);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(177, 73, 73);
    color: black; 
}

.floatimg{
    float: left;
}

.parrafo1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>

<body>

    <header>
        <nav class='navbar'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OPTIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <img src="./img/avatar.jpg" alt="" class="floatimg">

    <p class="parrafo1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum suscipit beatae doloribus provident adipisci ea. Ab aliquam cupiditate itaque commodi?</p>

</body>
```

Comment: tuve que copiar y pegar abajo de todo para que me deje hacer la consulta, ignoren eso. Gracias

Comment: Nota: Los enlaces dinámicos no sirven en stack overflow(porque este no está en el servidor), por lo que la imagen no se mostrará al menos que sea un enlace absoluto

Comment: Para el texto puedes hacer que tenga un contenedor padre que sea del largo de la pantalla y el texto dentro o ya sea de una etiqueta Center o le pones a la propiedad padre del texto text-align:Center; : <p style="text-align:center">Texto</p>